# route not found on ajax post

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to create a dependent select using ajax, here is my JS

```
$("#make").change(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "{{ url('chauffeur/ajax_vehicle_model') }}?make=" + $(this).val(),
        method: 'GET',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#model').html(data.html);
        }
    });
});
```

My routing looks like this

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth'], 'prefix' => 'admin', 'as' => 'admin.'], function () {
    Route::get('chauffeur/ajax_vehicle_model','Admin\ChauffeurController@get_vehicle_model');
});
```

And in my controller I have this

```
public function get_vehicle_model(Request $request)
{
    ....
}
```

But I get a 404 error, any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: where did you put the javascript code ? in a .js file or blade file?

Comment: @yasaryousuf  in the blade file between `@section('javascript')` and `@endsection`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your route like this

**routing file**

```
Route::get('chauffeur/ajax_vehicle_model', ['as'=> 'chauffeur.ajax.vehicle',  'uses' => 'Admin\ChauffeurController@get_vehicle_model']);
```

Now your js code should be like this (if your js code is in `.blade.php` file)

```
$("#make").change(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "{{ route('chauffeur.ajax.vehicle') }}?make=" + $(this).val(),
        method: 'GET',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#model').html(data.html);
        }
    });
});
```

try this.

Comment: had to put change route in JS to `route('admin.chauffeur.ajax.vehicle')`

Answer (score 1):

As you see, you have an argument in your route group `prefix`, with the value `admin`.

This prefixes your routes inside that route group with `admin`. This way, your url in JS should look like:

```
url(“admin/chauffeur/ajax_vehicle_model”)
```